# XSLT Failing to Match, Namespace and Doctype Issues

Tags: xml, xslt, internet-explorer-8

When applying the XSLT to XML file listed below no match is ever found. This transform is being preformed client-side in Internet Explorer 8 using the Msxml2 library. While my ultimate application is far more complex, the simple test below fails.

XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM 'xmlschemas/domino_8_5_3.dtd'>
<document xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl' version='8.5' maintenanceversion='3.0'
 replicaid='862570A600460D8C' form='Appeal'>
<item name="criteria"></item>
</document>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:dxl="http://www.lotus.com/dxl" >

<xsl:template match="dxl:document">
    <xsl:text>It worked!</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've read countless 'solutions' about name spaces and tried them all... it always fails to match. In a couple scenarios I was able to get the whole document by removing the !DOCTYPE tag, but the matching did then not work (just returned all text and never showed "It worked!"

**EDIT:** The same code which does the transform works in another part of my application, but not in this case. Here's the code:

```
var xml2;
var xsl2;

$.get("test2.xml", function(data) { getXSL(data); });

function getXSL(data) {
    xml2 = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    xml2.loadXML(data);

    $.get("test2.xsl", function(data) { transformCriteriaXML(data); });
}

function transformCriteriaXML(data) {
    xsl2 = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    xsl2.loadXML(data);

    var outFile;
    var objFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    outFile = "output.txt";
    var objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile, true);
    objFile.Write(xml2.transformNode(xsl2));
    objFile.Close();
}
```

Different operating systems and different IE versions are non-negotiable as this is a company application and the only available IE is version 8.0. (The reason the above code allows me to write a file to the local PC is because it's an HTML Application (.hta) and thus security restrictions are disabled.)

output.txt from above only ever shows `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.

Comment: You need to edit the question and provide a complete (but small) example of the client-side code -- so that people could independently repro the issue. Untill this is done, this question is rather hanging in the air -- allowing different interpretations and forcing people to resort to guesses. Also, why IE8? The latest released MS browser -- both for Win 7 and Win 8 is IE10. Quite important, I believe that you don't need the DTD (at least XSLT makes very little if any use of it). Even if intended for validation, this is better done offline and not thousands of times --  on each http request.

Comment: Try adding: `xml2.async = false;` and `xsl2.async = false;` before each call to the `Load()` method. See a working example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms761399(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: I tried it with the flag set both ways with my tests, and it seems instead to be MSXML refusing to generate an invalid XML document for output. See my answer below.

Comment: @Borodin, Yes, but the OP is using `TransformNode()` -- not `TransformNodeToObject()`. It was 10 years ago when I was using MSXML actively for the last time ...

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: You're quite right: I hadn't studied the C++ code he showed. When I change to using `transformNode` instead everything works fine. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Borodin, I think he is using JS code.

Comment: Nick Betcher -- Try checking `xml2.parseError.errorCode != 0` and also `xsl2.parseError.errorCode` immediately after `Load()` . Most probably there are some errors and the error messages will show what went wrong.

Comment: Interestingly enough, when the document has the DTD defined MSXML2 reports and error of `DTD Prohibited`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of MSXML2 is version 2.6, which was last updated in 2004 and is considered obsolete.

I would use a different processing engine if I were you, as this stylesheet works fine for me on all the engines I have access to.

May we know what is in your DTD? I can't think of anything that would prevent the transform from going ahead but it might be nice to see it.

The latest version of MSXML is version 6.0, which is pre-installed on Windows 7. It is available for download from the [Microsoft Download Centre](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3988) for XP.

---

**Update**

OK I have had some success. I have found what is probably a bug in MSXML, in that it won't create anything that isn't valid XML as output - even if the `output` element in the stylesheet says `method="text"`. That's contrary to the XSLT standard, but is typical Microsoft.

See [this similar problem on GNT](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/text-output-msxml-help-43901952.html). It looks like the error is because the `DOMDocument.transformNodeToObject` is being used to transform to another `DOMDocument` object, which can't represent plain text. Apparently it will also accept a simple stream object here, but I didn't look any further as text output isn't a requirement here.

I have got exactly your code working if I remove the `DOCTYPE` from the XML and also add a root element around the text your stylesheet outputs, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:dxl="http://www.lotus.com/dxl">

  <xsl:template match="dxl:document">
    <root>
      <xsl:text>It worked!</xsl:text>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which produces this output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<root xmlns:dxl="http://www.lotus.com/dxl">It worked!</root>
```

Comment: The DTD is 200KB large, but whether it's accessible by IE at transform time does not change the result of the transform. What other XSLT engines are suggested? Preferably one that is already installed by default on Windows XP/7 machines.

Comment: I have added to my answer to indicate where you can fetch the latest MSXML.

Comment: MSXML version 6.0 is instantiated by calling MSXML2 and specifying the version number in the class. e.g. (and this is how I call it) `new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")`. You're saying when you call this that it functions correctly?

Comment: Ah OK. You're talking about the ProgID. They froze the prefix at MXSML 2.0, for which the ProgID was `MSXML2.DOMDocument`. For 3.0 it was `MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0` and it is the suffix that has changed since then. Thanks Microsoft for being so confusing.

Comment: I'm using MSXML 4.0 as I don't have 6.0 on my XML editor. I will throw something together to try it with 6.0 but I doubt if it will fail. The output is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>It worked!`. I don't suppose you'e missing it because it's hidden behind the XML declaration on the same line?

Comment: At first I thought I was missing it so I went back and double checked many test cases, but I wasn't just missing it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29809/discussion-between-borodin-and-nick-betcher)

Comment: Marking as correct and answered, although unfortunately on a large scale it still does not work. I suspect a different problem though.